# Meteor AWS4 + Appstream

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have two questions related to AWS Signing 4 (AWS4) and Appstream:

AWS4:

1) How to make a sign request version 4 using Meteor. What are the tools available for that.

Appstream:

1) Each user connects to application, but when user want to save some files related to application let's say a Game is running which saves game files of the user, then how to create that system in which each user can resume working from the state which they left. How to handle this on AWS Appstream? (e.g. Resuming last saved Game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shalabh Sharma,

If you're making any request HTTP requests to any service you'll more than likely want to add the HTTP package; http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http.

The second part of your question, is really dependent on how you'd like to handle that. You can set a property ({key,value}) inside of the document that flags if a user has paused the game.

For example;

The user is playing the game, then pauses it. The flag in the document gets set to; "pausedGame", true. The user returns and sees their game paused clicks on it and all of the data at the point of which they last left get's returned to it's state.

Hopefully this helps.